# run Nunit 3.0.1 in Gallio 3.4.14.0

Tags: nunit, gallio

I changed the Gallio.NUnitAdapterLatest.plugin with a binding redirect to this : oldVersion="2.6.0.0-3.0.5813.39032".
I also overwrote tje previous dlls in the latest subfolder.
I changed all occurences in the config file to no avail.
I also debugged the source code but did not manage to make it take my dlls.

What itches me is "compatiblity" between 2.6.x and 3.0 of nunit since as I read it somewhere, this trick can only be done if compatibility between the two dlls are maintained, which I am not sure.

I compiled Gallio in X86, for a .Net 4 test project.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I very highly doubt that you will get NUnit 3.0 running under Gallio's adapter. NUnit 3 is a nearly complete rewrite and it's engine is not at all compatible with the 2.6 core.

In order to get it working, you will need to create a new NUnit3 adapter for Gallio. Since Gallio is a [dead project](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gallio-dev/4IGEtezldik), I wouldn't expend the effort. Gallio's test runner is nice, but why are you still using it to run NUnit tests?

Comment: Our shared current infra is using Sonar + Gallio, although, the next version of sonar is dropping (at last), dead Gallio.